# Как подключить CUDA (которой нету в системных путях) через cmake?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cuda

Если куда стоит в системе, там все просто. Макрос сам подхватит компилятор и соберет.
Но мне надо задавать пути до несистемной CUDA через аргументы CMake

вот команда , которая в CMakeSettings.json в VisualStudio:

```
"cmakeCommandArgs": "-DPRODUCT_NAME=<имя продукта> -DOPENCV_PATH=C:/work/modules/opencv -DSERIAL_NUMBER=6666-6666-6666-6666 -DSVN_REV=6666",
```

Очень желательно бы в этой строке написать нечто похожее на CUDA_PATH=C:/work/modules/CUDA/bin

чтобы я не писал, чтобы не делал, все равно пишет No CUDA toolset found.

Comment: поидей должно быть достаточно задать `CMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER` и, может быть, `CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, подразумевая, что используется `cmake`'овская поддержка CUDA из коробки, а не `FindCUDA`...

Answer (score 0):

```
set(ENV{CUDA_PATH} "C:\\work\\pds\\modules\\CUDA")
set(ENV{CUDA_PATH_V11_0} "C:\\work\\pds\\modules\\CUDA")
set(ENV{CUDACXX} "C:\\work\\pds\\modules\\CUDA\\bin\\nvcc.exe")
set(ENV{PATH} "C:\\work\\pds\\modules\\CUDA\\bin:$ENV{PATH}")
set(ENV{PATH} "C:\\work\\pds\\modules\\CUDA\\libnvvp:$ENV{PATH}")
enable_language(CUDA)
```